# jQuery ajax done callback behaves strange in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have an issue with jQuery 1.7.1 and the ajax function in firefox. 
I am doing an ajax call that requests json from a CMIS server. In chrome everything works fine. Let me give you an example:

```
function ajaxCall(url, requestType, isAsync, parameters, doneCb, failCb) {
    $.ajax(url, {
        type: requestType,
        async: isAsync,
        data: parameters
    }).done(
        alert("test"),
        // the following function gets not executed in firefox with async: true
        function (result) {
            doneCb(result);
        }).fail(function (cause) {
            failCb(cause);
        });
}
```

The strange thing in firefox is that if I am using async: false everything works like a charm. In case I use async: true the done callback is also executed and the alert pop up with the message "test" appears. BUT the function after the alert doesn't get executed.
I googled a lot and couldn't find a solution for this problem.

You are my last hope ;)

Thanks and Best Regards,
Simon

I also tried the old fashioned way but the result is still the same - the success function doesn't get called in firefox if async is true.

```
 $.ajax(url, {
        type: requestType,
        async: isAsync,            
        data: parameters,
        success: function(result){
            doneCb(result);
        },
        error: function(cause){
            failCb(cause);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Removed my answer. Just noticed your using Jquery 1.7. This advice is for Jquery 1.8+. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

That code is taking the `alert` and assigning what it returns to the first argument of done. It is executing when the function is being initialized, not when the `done()` method is actually called.

It should look like

```
.done( 
    function() { alert("test") },
    function() { ... }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my original code I do not have the alert. I just placed it there to see whats going on. If I am executing the code without the alert the function is also never called :(